# Array address in MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips

In Section 2.14 (pp 141) in Patterson and Hennessy (5th Ed), the authors write that "to set `array[i]` to 0, we must first get its address. Start by multiplying `i` by 4 to get the byte address: `loop1: sll $t1, $t0, 2`".

I do not understand why we must multiply by 4 to get the byte address. Could it be because 1 word = 32 bits, which is 4 bytes?

Comment: What is the type of `array`? How many bytes in size are each of its members? (There is your answer.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, memory [chip] is addressable by individual bytes, so the very first word occupies four addresses: 0, 1, 2, 3. Each is 8 bits = 1 byte, together they form 32 bit value = 1 word (in MIPS world `word` = 32 bits). The order of them can be configured IIRC, but usually little-endian is assumed, so when loading whole `word`, the four bytes `0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78` form a word value `0x78563412`.

So to read consecutively by-words you have to adjust your address by +-4. If you have byte array, then the address can be adjusted by +-1, and half-words occupy 2 bytes, so +-2 addressing would do.